New notebooks added to databricks git folder not showing as changes and not able to commit and push
I have created a git folder in my databricks user folder and cloned my project repository from GitHub. Then created a new feature branch and added a new notebook. When I try to commit and push the new file, it is showing as no changed files. This done in azure databricks. Repository is configured using personal access token. Is there anything I have to do to add the new file to repository.

There is "bug" in Databricks Repos that sometimes is misleading and it is related to Access Tokens.
Try re-generating your access token, replace it in GIT Connection and try again.
If you done everything correctly - any time you add any kind of file to your FOLDER that is related/connected to git repo and COMMIT your changes, it will create file in Remote repository. So make sure you add Notebook to appropriate folder.
You can also post screenshot if above solution won't help.

After updating the token also issue not resolved. If I am doing any change in already existing file, changes will be shown. But if add a new notebook, it is not showing as a change.

Issue got resolved. Notebook folder was mentioned in the gitignore file. Removed it and issue resolved
